# Unable to access the variable inside created() and use in template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My template code:

```
<div><font>{{ toCode }}</font></div>
```

Js code:

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
          toCode :""
          }
},
created(){
Event.$on("code", arg => {
      this.toCode = arg.name;
      console.log(this.toCode);// returns code in console but unable to use in template
    });
}
}
```

Need to use the variable in vue template.

Comment: how does this even work? your created is inside your data, and there is missing closing tags

Comment: Sorry now i have edited my code....

Comment: are you sure arg.name is not empty?

Comment: yes arg.name is not empty

Comment: I dont know what fires that "code" event, but the problem need to be elsewhere, unless i am not seeing something really obvious, the code that you posted seems ok

Comment: What error or output are you seeing? Is there an error message or is the console output just different to what is displayed in the template?

Comment: No errors found in console